# Is there a way to use PC browser bookmarklets with the Android Browser or Dolphin HD?

Tags: browser, browser-add-ons, bookmarklets, javascript

Can I make these work on Android or is there a google place to create or convert bookmarklets to make them Android Compatible?

Comment: see also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1054/is-there-a-way-to-use-userscripts-greasemonkey-scripts-on-the-android-browser-o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally got it to work and it wasn't complicated at all.

Simply create a bookmark and paste the javascript into the URL field.  I've tried it on this bookmarklet that does a google definition search:

`javascript: s = (window.getSelection ? window.getSelection() : document.getSelection ? document.getSelection() : document.selection.createRange().text); if (s == '') { l = parent.frames.length; if (l != 1) { for (i = 0; i < l; i++) { s = parent.frames[i].document.getSelection ? parent.frames[i].document.getSelection() : parent.frames[i].document.selection.createRange().text; if (s) { break; } } } } if (s == '') { void( s = prompt('Google Define:
Enter a term or mark some text.','') ); } if (s) { s = String(s); s = s.replace(/^s*|s*$/g,''); s = escape(s);void( bmw = open('http://www.google.com/search?num=100&start=0&q=define:'+s+'','GoogleDefineBM'+String(Math.round(Math.random()*1000))) );}`

To get it saved as a bookmark I just saved the text in evernote then copied it on my phone an pasted it in the url field of "new bookmark."  To make it even easier to access I created a custom dolphin gesture that opens it as "Go To URL".  Now when I'm browsing and I want to lookup a word I hit the gesture button and draw a "d" and it brings up a popup that allows me to lookup the word.

I've only tried this on Dolphin Browser HD.

Comment: Unfortunately on Firefox and Chrome for Android it doesn't work.

Comment: But with Dolphin Browser it does work.

Answer (score 3):

Works in Chrome mobile. Here's the recipe:

#### PREPARE

Create a bookmarklet = add a script to your bookmarks:

- on Chrome PC¹, then sync (so your bookmarks show up in Chrome mobile on your phone)
- or directly in Chrome mobile on your phone²

#### USE

Do not invoke/call the script (on phone) by looking it up in Chrome Bookmarks (menu [ **⋮** ] / Bookmarks) → that doesn't work. You have to tap the URL bar and start typing the bookmarklet's name. Select the bookmarklet from the list (it'll begin with *javascript:blahblahblah…*).

---

¹) on any webpage hit Chrome's button [ **⭐** ] on URL bar then [**More**] in the popup that appears, then enter the bookmarklet name, URL (=code beginning with *javascript:blahblahblah…*), optionally choose folder, then hit [**Save**]

²) on any webpage hit Chrome's button [ **⋮** ] then [ **⭐** ] then [**Edit**] on a bar that shows down the screen, then enter the bookmarklet name, URL (=code beginning with *javascript:blahblahblah…*), optionally choose folder, then hit [**←**] to save and go back

Answer (score 0):

It isn't so much being "Android compatible" as being compatible with the specific browser.

That being said... I haven't gotten URL-based javascript to execute in Dolphin, but that proves nothing.

Answer (score 0):

"Simply create a bookmark and paste the javascript into the URL field."

Bookmark a page that you have not bookmarked, then modify the bookmark, Name, Address, Folder (to something like "Bookmarklets"), and Assign a Gesture, then Add.

Suggest you create a gesture to create a bookmark and draw a five pointed star as that gesture. (or use the "+" at the left end of the address bar.)

For more information see http://dmcritchie.mvps.org/dolphin/dolphin_mygestures.htm

Comment: This does not work in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

[Chrome to Phone](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.chrometophone) and also...

[Phone to Chrome](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.chrometophone),

Once the the linkys gets synchronized, then its merely a matter of bookmarking it.

The only onus, is that Chrome is installed on the PC Desktop, in that way, linkys can be shared.