# Is there a way to use Userscripts / Greasemonkey Scripts on the Android Browser or Dolphin HD?

Tags: browser, browser-add-ons, javascript

I would like to be able to use [userscripts](http://userscripts.org/) in Android.  Is this even possible?  I read that it was a couple months back and tried a tutorial which I can no longer find but it didn't work.

This question may be related to [this other one](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1053/is-there-a-way-to-use-pc-browser-bookmarklets-with-the-android-browser-or-dolphin) I submitted but I believe they may have totally different answers.

Comment: see also: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1053/is-there-a-way-to-use-pc-browser-bookmarklets-with-the-android-browser-or-dolphin

Comment: I just installed tampermonkey on FIREFOX **NIGHTLY** on android successfully , using this workaround https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXcg8r0c-Lk

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [OilCan](http://oilcan.jsharkey.org/) - "Greasemonkey on steroids for Android".

Comment: Have you tried it?  I'm pretty sure this is the one I tried but couldn't get to work.  It was a while ago when I was still new to Android so I might have better luck now.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet. Looks cool though so I will give it a try soon and see what happens.

Answer (score 15):

### 2019 Update:

My preferred way to get userscripts on Android would now be to use the Firefox browser, which has working, well-maintained Add-ons available for both Greasemonkey and Tampermonkey (search for them through the Add-ons menu in the Firefox app).

Pasting the javascript into the address bar still works (at least on Chrome), but note that Chrome now strips out the `javascript:` prefix when you paste in the code.  If you don't retype it, it will just do a web search.

The mobile versions of Chrome and Opera (also now based on Chromium) don't support userscript add-ons, but the Tampermonkey standalone app is still available from the Play Store.  It hasn't been updated since 2013 but still just about works.  However, given its age, it won't support many of the features of the current Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey API, or modern websites in general.  As a result, many userscripts won't work without modification.  It's also tricky to figure out how to install them in the first player (use the 'Textarea' utility hidden under the Advanced Settings).  There are also Tampermonkey extensions for the Dolphin and UC browsers available in the Play Store.  I haven't tried them, but they haven't been updated since 2016.

### Original 2013 answer:

Solution 1. Use [Tampermonkey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.biniok.tampermonkey). Tampermonkey is more popular as an extension for Chrome, but it is also available as a standalone Android app. It functions as a lightweight browser, and allows you to manage and automatically run user scripts. Unfortunately it doesn't have many of the features found on other popular browsers, but it does support the Greasemonkey API.

Solution 2. Use Opera Mobile, which has built-in support for userscripts, but no script management features, and doesn't support the Greasemonkey API. Navigate to the User Prefs section of `opera:config`, then tick "Always Load User JavaScript" and "User JavaScript". Enter the path to a folder (not a file) in the "User JavaScript File" field (I use /sdcard/userscripts/), then store the settings. Save your userscript in that folder with a `.user.js` extension.  NB this works in OM12, but the OM14 beta doesn't seem to support userscripts at present.

Solution 3. Launch your userscript manually via a bookmarklet or pasting this javascript directly into the browser address bar:

```
javascript:(function(){var a=document.createElement("script");a.src="http://path.to/myscript.user.js";document.head.appendChild(a);})();
```

This technique is tedious, but the principle should work in most browsers. You don't get Greasemonkey API support though. The code above should work without modification in the stock Android browser, and can be saved as a bookmarklet. In Chrome Mobile the space in the `var a` needs escaping, i.e. `var%20a=`, and bookmarklets don't seem to work, so you have to paste manually every time.

Comment: I guess you should advise the people who use the 3rd option. The userscript engine is more than append a js file to the current dom. Is not only the API, it's the sandbox features.

Comment: The current version of Opera for Android does not support user javascript.

Comment: Option 3 did not work for me, unfortunately.  It just google-searched the string until I realized that the `javascript:` portion at the front wasn't actually pasting into the URL bar (how annoying!)

Comment: Please note that a script won't load if you are on a `https://` site but load s script from `http://` and also, in newer browsers, you may have to fiddle around with `about:config` to enable loading of scripts from another domain on some sites who disable it in their `<meta>` tag in their `<head>` section

Comment: My Firefox android is not compatible with either tampermonkey or greasemonkey addons. Are you sure ?

Comment: This answer is out of date. Firefox for Android no longer supports these add-ons unless you use Firefox Nightly, which is not ideal for most users.

Answer (score 2):

Use either the [Habit Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.ddo.pigsty.HabitBrowser) or [Slepnir Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.fenrir.android.sleipnir) apps. They both support Userscripts. I had to tweak my scripts slightly to get them working (they handle events differently) but they both work really well.

Comment: Do you have any instructions on how to install a userscript with either? I played around with Sleipnir for an hour and could not figure out how to do so.

Answer (score 2):

There is a Greasemonkey-like add-on for Dolphin called [Tampermonkey](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.tampermonkey.dolphin&hl=en). There is also a stand-alone Tampermonkey app, but Dolphin is a more full-fledged browser than that thing.

There is also a similar add-on for Firefox for Android, called [USI](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/userunified-script-injector/).

Comment: Dear lord, Tampermonkey's browser is awful. No cookies, no bookmarks, no passwords, no tabs.  It's the barest of barebones and not even worth using.

Comment: Firefox does support plugins on mobile, woot.

Answer (score 1):

You can run userscripts on your phone by installing [Violentmonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/violentmonkey/jinjaccalgkegednnccohejagnlnfdag) on [Kiwi Browser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiwibrowser.browser) or [Iceraven](https://github.com/fork-maintainers/iceraven-browser).