# Prevent particular website pages from appearing in Google search [phone]

Tags: browser, chrome-for-android

How do I prevent links to a particular website from showing in search results on chrome, on my mobile?

For example I want to see a video of maybe cows dancing

But I don't want to see any links related to dailymotion.com.

Is there any way I can filter those results out?

(If this doesn't belong here, please leave a comment as to where I can ask this. I feel this could be helpful for others too so I asked it here)

Comment: You could check if Chrome on Android can run "UserScripts". If it does, take a look at [Google site: Tool (Site results / Exclude sites)](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/1679-google-site-tool-site-results-exclude-sites). That's what I use with Firefox on my desktop, works fine.

Comment: I think it's not possible on the phone

Comment: Then maybe think again:) See: [Is there a way to use Userscripts / Greasemonkey Scripts on the Android Browser or Dolphin HD?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1054/16575)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to filter only some searches when you need it, and not permanently ban sites. Simply including `-site:dailymotion.com` in the search query should do the trick (make sure not to omit the '-').

If you want to permanently ban a site, try the following:

Some AdBlock apps exist that allow you to blacklist certain URLs. I'm not sure though if this would work with google searches (as they are only links to the host and not resources pulled from the host), but it's worth giving it a shot.

Comment: Yes! Your first suggestion works!

Comment: Did you expect it to not work? ;-)

Comment: @AmanThakkar There you go with more: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en Use them in combination, just like the demo ionree gave.