# How do I save `javascript:` URLs in Android's browser?

Tags: browser, bookmarks, javascript, bookmarklets

I've tried tap & hold, like regular URLs, but the menu never pops up. Is there a way to enable that or do I just have to copy and paste the URL into a bookmark ([like this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/1053/is-there-a-way-to-use-pc-browser-bookmarklets-with-the-android-browser-or-dolphin/2685#2685))?

Here's the page I was trying to use:
http://www.delicious.com/help/bookmarklets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing [WiFi Keyboard](http://www.appbrain.com/app/wifi-keyboard/com.volosyukivan) as suggested by [GAThrawn](https://android.stackexchange.com/users/156/gathrawn) made input much easier.

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to copy and paste.  I don't know why the long click doesn't work, but I assume because the url doesn't start with "http".

I've found the easiest way to create bookmarklets is to do it on the PC and then import the bookmarks, or by copying the text of the js url to a text file, emailing or dropboxing it to my phone and then copying & pasting the text into a bookmark.

Comment: Another easy way to get the text on is with apps like WiFi Keyboard that let you control your phone with a PC keyboard, and copy and paste text from pc to phone. This is how I do it. http://www.appbrain.com/app/wifi-keyboard/com.volosyukivan